# Eclipse Jar export script

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, build-script

I have a shared project that I'd like to split up in Eclipse.
It's an android shared library which some packages should just be jar files others need to be smaller shared libraries.

What is the best way to handle this other than manually creating smaller projects?

Also is there a way to create a script to create exported jar files from eclipse if I gave it a project path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing a [Ant script](http://ant.apache.org/) that generate different JARs?

References for the jar task : [Intro tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html), [Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), [More examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/Anttaskjar.htm)

Comment: When you export with Eclipse, you can select the option to generate the ant script. Later on, you simply run the ant script and it will build the jar automatically each time.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic shell script for creating JAR file from a standard Eclipse Dynamic Java project. Uses RAM file system (/dev/shm) on Linux systems.

```
#!/bin/sh

UTILITY=$(basename $0)

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "usage: $UTILITY [-s] <jar-directory>..."
    echo "       -s ..... With source"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" == "-s" ] ; then
    WITH_SOURCE=1
    shift
fi

while [ ! -z "$1" ] ; do
    JAR_DIR=$1

    shift

    if [ ! -d $JAR_DIR ] ; then
        echo "\"$JAR_DIR\" is not a directory"
        continue
    fi

    if [ ! -d $JAR_DIR/bin ] ; then
        echo "\"$JAR_DIR\" is not a Java JAR directory"
        continue
    fi

    TMP_DIR=/dev/shm/${JAR_DIR}.$$.tmp
    JAR_FILE=/dev/shm/${JAR_DIR}.jar

    mkdir $TMP_DIR

    pushd $JAR_DIR > /dev/null
    cp -r bin/* $TMP_DIR
    [ ! -z "$WITH_SOURCE" ] && cp -r src/* $TMP_DIR
    cd $TMP_DIR > /dev/null
    [ -e $JAR_FILE ] && rm -f $JAR_FILE
    jar cf $JAR_FILE .
    ls -lsF $JAR_FILE
    popd > /dev/null

    rm -rf $TMP_DIR
done
```